# EcmaScript 6: New operator in tail position

Tags: javascript, tail-recursion, ecmascript-6

The upcoming ES6 standard demands that an expression of the form `new f(x)` in tail position is a tail call.

I can think of a number of artificial examples where this does matter, e.g.

```
function Sum(n, m) {
  if (n === 0) {
    this.m = m;
  } else {
    return new Sum(n - 1, n + m);
  }
}

function f(n) {
  return new Sum(n, 0).m;
}

f(1000000)
```

but are there any real world use cases?

P.S.: Here is the specification where it the new operator in tail position is handled: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-expression-rules

Comment: Your example doesn't work..

Comment: Could you elaborate? (Corrected typos.)

Comment: Please link to the specific ES6 draft (and section) that you are referring to.  There's nothing fancy about the code block you've provided and it's not clear what information you are looking for.

Comment: @Digigizmo Added a link. My code block is not fancy, no, but now one would code a thing like that. One would rather drop all the `new`s and access `Sum` as an ordinary function.

Comment: @Marc I think you misunderstand the *new*. It's a new feature of ES6, but you're not supposed to use `new` keyword. It's a regular function call in tail position.

Comment: @lyschoening The `new` in my code above is the `new` keyword. It's not a regular function call. In the ES6 draft it is demanded that such `new`s in tail position do not grow the stack.

Comment: To the one who downvoted my question: Would you care to explain your vote? Do you have a suggestion on how to improve the question?

Comment: @Marc sorry I misread your question to say that the spec demands that a tail call uses a new operator. If you edit your question I will upvote.

Comment: @lyschoening Thanks for replying. Does the new wording help you?

Comment: It was also good before—entirely my fault for misreading. I just needed the edit to be able to change my vote. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably something that was added for completeness more than anything else. After all, `new` isn't much more than a function call on a new object. There are a few examples that are not entirely contrived, such as this singly `LinkedList`:

```
function LinkedList(list, next = null) {
   this.next = next;
   this.value = list.pop();

   if(list.length == 0) {
       return this;
   } else {
       return new LinkedList(list, this);
   }
}

// > var l = new LinkedList([1,2,3]);
// undefined
// > l.value
// 1
// > l.next
// LinkedList {next: LinkedList, value: 2}
// > l.next.next
// LinkedList {next: null, value: 3}
```